# Angular textarea input not showing value/contents, despite showing up in html

Tags: html, angular

I insert a textarea component into my template like so:

```html
<div class="card-body" *ngIf="isEditing">
    <app-text-area input-id="body" input-value="This is my default input value"></app-text-area>
</div>
```

The template of `app-text-area` is like so:

```html
<textarea
    placeholder="This is my placeholder"
    [name]="inputID"
    (input)="onInputChanged($event)"
    ngModel>
    {{ inputValue }}
</textarea>
```

The subsequent rendered HTML is like so:

```html
<textarea _ngcontent-owj-c62="" placeholder="This is my placeholder" ngmodel="" ng-reflect-model="" ng-reflect-name="body" class="ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched">
     This is my default input value
</textarea>
```

However on the actual page, the `inputValue` text doesn't show up anywhere, the textarea acts as though it is empty, even showing the placeholder text. I can see the value in the html, though when I start typing in the box it replaces it as if it weren't there. The console shows no errors.

If I remove `ngModel` from the textarea, it fixes it

My `app-text-area` component ts is:

```js
import { Component, EventEmitter, Input, OnInit, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { ControlContainer, NgForm } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-text-area',
  templateUrl: './text-area.component.html',
  viewProviders: [ { provide: ControlContainer, useExisting: NgForm } ],
  styleUrls: ['./text-area.component.scss']
})
export class TextAreaComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input("input-id") public inputID: string = "text";
  @Input("input-value") public inputValue: string;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  public onInputChanged(event: Event):void {
    let newValue = (event.target as HTMLTextAreaElement).value;
    this.inputValue = newValue;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hard to help without seeing the component.ts file
But a solution would be something in the lines of the following:

HTML template:

```
<textarea
    
    [name]="inputID"
    (input)="onInputChanged($event)"
    [value]="inputValue">


 </textarea>
<p>{{inputValue}}</p>
```

And the component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-text-area',
  templateUrl: './text-area.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./text-area.component.css']
})
export class TextAreaComponent implements OnInit {
inputID:number=1;
inputValue:string="This is my placeholder";
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
onInputChanged(event:any){
  this.inputValue=event.target.value;
  
}
}
```

This would set the initial value as "This is my placeholder" and would update the value on each change in the input displayed inside the p tag

Comment: I need the `inputValue` to be inside the `textarea`, so that users can edit it. If I do that, it doesn't show up. I've also added my component file to the question.

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you want to do, since the inputValue will be exactly what the user inputs, or the initial value set as 'placeholder' which can be edited but will be replaced for whatever the user inputs.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix this by setting `[ngModel]="inputValue"` instead of the `defaultValue`, `value`, or placing `inputValue` inside the textarea itself.